# Dynamically assign IdProperty for a Elasticsearch type in NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to build a generic data loader using NEST client in C# and using Elasticsearch v5.x. I am able to define custom class mapping to a type on my ES index and also specifically mention which property should be treated as id. This works fine and I am able to use the bulk API to load the data.

```
  [ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "col1")]
  public class Table1
  {    
     public int col1 { get; set; }
     public string col2 { get; set; }
     public string col3 { get; set; }
  }
```

However, this will need me to define the class every time that I have to load a new type to the index. So I want to build a generic load utility to which I can provide a XML input, dynamically generate a class object and for that class object, I need to set the IdProperty. I am still trying to figure out how to build a dynamic object on the fly and have come across few samples that I am going to try out this week.

So lets say that I am able to get past that hurdle, my next question is how do I set the IdProperty dynamically during run time? Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using [`System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zz5httw(v=vs.110).aspx), it is possible to add attributes to types at runtime, ***so long as `TypeDescriptor` is used to retrieve those attributes***. NEST however does not use `TypeDescriptor`, so it is not possible to take this route.

By default, [NEST will look for a property with the case-insensitive name `"Id"` to use as the id for a document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/ids-inference.html), if no `ElasticsearchTypeAttribute` with `IdProperty` is present and no inferred mapping has been set up on `ConnectionSettings`. So, you could always ensure that your types have an `Id` property.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I took a slightly different route to address the main problem. I am now converting my XML to Json and generate raw Json which I am using to index the documents. In between, i have a configuration set to identify which property from Json should be treated as Id and I am dynamically adding the id properly. Once the json is built, I am using the lowlevel client's bulk method.

Comment: Also to add, i tried using dynamic with ExpandoObject for similar results i.e. to add id attribute dynamically. It works for smaller set of data. But for larger set, I started getting Stackoverflow exception (probably both due to bad coding and dynamic object limitations). So I did not pursue that approach further.